# For a huge non distributed database doesn't it still make sense to partition large tables into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

For example using a modulo 1024 hash on the auto incrementing index to specify which table the content is in, then querying that table. This way if there's millions of posts in the future table sorting and selecting won't be slow, at the expense of not going as easily searchable. Is there any other downsides to partitioning a large table into many many smaller tables? Like blog post comments or forum thread replies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitioning a table doesn't automatically make all queries against it faster. For instance, you could run a query searching for a particular userid, which is not the partitioning column. Then the query would have to search every partition anyway.

So you have to design the partitioning to match the query terms you want to optimize for.

Sometimes there's no way to do this, either because you have a variety of searches with different terms, or else the column in your search term can't be put into the primary key of the table (remember that MySQL partitioning columns must be included in the primary/unique keys of the table).

That said, in cases when you can partition in a manner that allows partition pruning to speed up the queries you want to prioritize, then yes, partitioning can give a lot of benefit. How much benefit depends on a lot of other factors.